# what is sharp sign in the name of .cpp files?

Tags: emacs, filenames

Sometimes when I create .cpp or .sh files, for example, a.cpp, I see another file created and named #a.cpp#, I'm using ubuntu, what is that file?

Comment: Some text editors use this convention for temporary/backup files while editing - they should get cleaned up after you exit the editor.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto_002dSaving.html, this is the notation how emacs handles its autosave files.

After closing and saving the file, it should dissapear.